# Nodejs failing to establish tls connection with RDS

Tags: node.js, postgresql, amazon-web-services, ssl

I have the following code

```js
const { Client } = require('pg')

const client = new Client({
  client: 'postgresql',
  connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  ssl: { 
    rejectUnauthorized: true,
  },
})

client.connect((err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error('connection error', err.stack)
  } else {
    console.log('connected')
  }
})
```

I export

```
export DATABASE_URL=postgres://myuser:mypassword@myrds.123456789.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com/postgres?ssl=true
```

This fails with:

```
connection error Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1497:34)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:932:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:706:12)
```

AFAIK RDS uses AWS Trust services.

This authority is trusted by my laptop, since a `psql` command succeeds with the above url.

Why does `nodejs` fails? There is no "self signed certificate" in the chain...

Using `node 14.16` and `pg@8.9`

**update**: Per [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html) documentation, I have downloaded the `global-bundle` [pem](https://truststore.pki.rds.amazonaws.com/global/global-bundle.pem) and I have modified my code as follows

```js
const { Client } = require('pg')
const fs = require('fs')

const client = new Client({
  client: 'postgresql',
  connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  ssl: { 
    rejectUnauthorized: true,
    ca: fs.readFileSync('global-bundle.pem').toString(),
  },
})

client.connect((err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error('connection error', err.stack)
  } else {
    console.log('connected')
  }
})
```

but I am still getting the same error...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `psql` is verifying the certificate chain based on that  URL. You would [need to pass](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNECT-SSLMODE) `sslmode=verify-ca` or `sslmode=verify-full` for `psql` to verify the certificate chain.

I also don't think AWS RDS uses AWS Trust services for SSL certificates. Per [the RDS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html), AWS uses an RDS certificate authority, and you would need to download the root certificates and configure NodeJS to use those for validation.

Comment: Good catch on the AWS TS CA misconcepton; I have tried to download the [global-bundle](https://truststore.pki.rds.amazonaws.com/global/global-bundle.pem) and pass it as `ca` option in the `ssl` block but still I get the same error.

Comment: I have updated my original question accordingly

Comment: I am also enforcing `ssl` in my RDS parameter group FWIW `rds.force_ssl` is set to `1`

Comment: Hi @pkaramol, Have you got a solution for this Issue? I'm also getting same error

Answer (score 0):

It works if you use: rejectUnauthorized: false. Self signed certificates are covered here: https://node-postgres.com/features/ssl

My pg version is 8.10.